# How do I make Kotlin allow to return a object that has a generic which is a subtype of the expected return value?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I would like to do the following example in Kotlin:

```
open class A
class B: A()

class Baz<T>(val value: T)

fun doFoo(): Baz<A> {
  return doBar()
}

fun doBar(): Baz<B> {
  return Baz(B())
}
```

([Kotlin playground link](https://pl.kotl.in/CtsOR6I0G))

However, `return doBar()` doesn't compile complaining that `Baz<A>` is expected, but `Baz<B>` was provided.

Is there any way to do this?

> Note: I cannot change the signature of `doFoo` to return a `Baz<*>` because at some point up in the call hierarchy I need to access the inner part of Baz.

I would expect that Kotlin can automatically infer that this is valid, because `B` inherits from `A`. Is there a situation where this could not be safely inferred and that's why the compiler can't do it?

Is there any way I can do this without manually having to map every single `Baz<B>` into a `Baz<A>` ?

I even tried to make A an interface, but the error remains.

Comment: You can use the out keyword in Baz class like Baz<out T> so that Baz<B> is a subtype of Baz<A> when B is subtype of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing further research (especially reading the Kotlin docs around [Generics > Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance) (especially the section on [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)) I started to understand why this is an issue in general and as such can't be allowed by the compiler outright:

We cannot simply assume that it is safe to upcast, for example like in this example from the docs:

```java
List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> objs = strs; // !!! A compile-time error here saves us from a runtime exception later.
objs.add(1); // Put an Integer into a list of Strings
String s = strs.get(0); // !!! ClassCastException: Cannot cast Integer to String
```

This makes sense in the context of mutable objects. If you know the data structure though, to allow for this in Java one can use `Baz<? extends A>` or in Kotlin `Baz<out A>`. This now works:

```kotlin
open class A
class B: A()

class Baz<T>(val value: T)

fun doFoo(): Baz<out A> {
  return doBar()
}

fun doBar(): Baz<B> {
  return Baz(B())
}
```

([Kotlin playground link](https://pl.kotl.in/g9p6k42sY))